# QuantityForm does not work with MixedRadixQuantity?

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, units

**Bug introduced after 9.0 and in 10.1 or earlier, and persisting through 11.2 or later**

*From 10.1 to 10.3.1, `QuantityForm[q, "Abbreviation"]` outputs*
[image: this]

*From 10.4 to 11.0.1 or later, see below.*

---

`MixedRadixQuantity` creates a `Quantity` with `MixedMagnitude` and `MixedUnit`.

```
q = MixedRadixQuantity[{1, 1, 1}, {"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}];
q // InputForm
(* Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{1, 1, 1}], 
     MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]] *)
```

This displays as `1 degrees 1 arc minutes 1 arc seconds`, but I would like to display it as `1° 1' 1"`.

`QuantityForm` displays a `Quantity` in its different forms. However it does not work on `Quantity`s of `MixedMagnitude` and `MixedUnit`.

**Works on non-mixed:**

```
QuantityForm[
 Quantity[1, #] & /@ {"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}, "Abbreviation"]
```

> {1°, 1', 1"}

**Does not worked on mixed:**

```
QuantityForm[q, "Abbreviation"]
```

> 1 degrees 1 arc minutes 1 arc seconds

The documentation does not list this in **Possible Issues** so I'm thinking this is either a documentation bug or a bug with `QuantityForm`.

**CASE:3700749**

Comment: Also `UnitSimplify@q` results in `3661"`.